# MVC project what is the difference between PartialViewResult, ActionResult,ViewResult classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

MVC project 
what is the difference between

`PartialViewResult`

`ActionResult`

`ViewResult`

classes?

can anyone post brief introduction link?

Comment: Since your DisplayName `Borrower` is different from the property name `Name`, how would you expect mvc to magically guess what DisplayName you want?

Comment: You just change the question! if you want to ask another question, ask once more, don't edit old questions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx) - an abstract class that all actions in an ASP.NET MVC application should return a concrete instance of.
- [ViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult.aspx) - an implementation of ActionResult that is used to render a view using the specified view engine
- [PartialViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult.aspx) - an implementation of ActionResult that is used to render a partial view (without a layout) using the specified view engine

Answer (score 2):

Here are some resources to get you started:

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx) for the *ActionResult* class can be viewed here.

[ActionResult types in MVC2](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/03/actionresult-types-in-mvc2.aspx) is a good introduction.

[ASP.NET MVC ActionResults explained](http://rachelappel.com/asp.net-mvc-actionresults-explained) is some more information.

[What's the point of ActionResult return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289171/whats-the-point-of-actionresult-return-type) link refers to another Stack Overflow post.

[Difference Between ViewResult() and ActionResult()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743741/differnce-between-viewresult-and-actionresult) is another.